# load a webpage into a string ...fastest way

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How can I load a web-page into a string in .net ?

i want the fastest way possible ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the [DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=VS.100).aspx) method:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/");
}
```

---

VB.NET equivalent:

```
Using client = New WebClient()
    Dim result As String = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/")
End Using
```

Comment: is this C#...not ...vb ...is this the faster way?

Comment: Yes it is C#. Faster than what?

Comment: Given that you didn't tag your question as VB, how are we meant to guess?

Comment: I'm sure he means "fastest". Adrian: I'll bet you can bypass the Windows and poll your NIC hardware directly to get the "fastest" possible speed. Don't worry about it, though. Darin's answer is the best you're going to get within a reasonable programming environment.

Comment: @Adrian, posted VB.NET equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Short of writing your own HTTP client, you're pretty much stuck with [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (which leverages [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) for its work). A component of our website relies on downloading data from other webpages, and we recently replaced all of the code reliant on  [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)/[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) with our own [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) based code and gained considerable CPU cycles back, but it's a tricky job that will take one dev who is very familiar with HTTP protocol at least a week to complete. Not for the faint of heart.